# How can I synchronize DOM element width in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to synchronize the width of DOM elements such that the width is always the smallest width that can accommodate the content. I can successfully increase the size by $watching for an increase (based on [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411021/set-height-of-one-div-to-another-div-in-angularjs/28420703) & [ref2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/slJ7Xj3SYOk)), but I can't figure out how to shrink the element after it's been enlarged.

Angular directive:

```
app.directive('syncWidth', function () { //declaration; identifier master
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var linkElement = element[0];

      scope.$watch(
        function () {
          return (linkElement.scrollWidth);
        },
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue > oldValue) {
            scope.testWidth = {
              'min-width': newValue + 'px'
            }
          }
        },
        true
      );
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText">
<input type="text" ng-model="myText2">

<div sync-width="test" style="background-color: lightblue" ng-style="testWidth">1 [{{myText}}]</div>
<div sync-width="test" style="background-color: lightcoral" ng-style="testWidth">2 [{{myText2}}]</div>
```

I'm assuming the issue is that the two elements are referencing another. I'm thinking the pseudocode would look something like:

```
Set a global groupMinWidth variable
Detect element.contentWidth changed
If newContentWidth > groupMinWidth {
  groupMinWidth = newContentWidth;
}

If oldContentWidth == groupMinWidth {
  check all synchronized elements and set groupMinWidth to the largest contentWidth;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can't really understand your requirement.. there are two divs, once increase the width of one of them, you want to increase the other to the same width ? is that right ? when you shrink one of them, do you want to shrink the other to the same width ?

Comment: Correct, although the content will change dynamically (e.g. from the input boxes in my example). I've been able to expand each element as I add text, but I would like to shrink both of them if I delete text. Here's a plunker of what I have so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZsL3OnYwyglxEciSbXYp?p=preview

Comment: I still can't quite get it to work, but I think the (or at least a) solution might require nesting a <div> inside and grabbing the scroll-width from the child and using that with a widthManager that stores all the widths of the synchronized content and updates the parent (which will probably need to have an overflow:hidden property so it only gets its width updated via the script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now working on the plunkr but not fully working yet : https://plnkr.co/edit/6XfGMzI1su8cpHjkyDWC?p=preview . The point is $watching the change on the text, when the text gets reduced,  use a shared value/global value to record and check which one's width is the widest , set the `min-width` to that value to both of the elements.

===EDIT===

Finally make this work: https://plnkr.co/edit/c2FOu5LfPfGfnkU12KTG?p=preview

So the principle behind this is : I need a changeable div to measure the `scrollWidth/offsetWidth` when the content changed. So I add a new nested div which include the content. I made the inner div as a `float` and once   the content changed I will update the outer div's width by setting it's `width` to the inner div's width. The key point is because the inner div is FLOAT, it can overflows the outer div's right border, but the out div is watching the change on the content, so the outer div's width will be updated immediately.